# Android security patch level from the future?

Tags: ota-update, oneplus-one, cyanogen-os

Device: OnePlus One, non-rooted, stock Cyanogen OS

I installed an OTA update today (27 August 2016).

Now, the *Android security patch level* shows a date from the future (1 September 2016).

Why is it such a date?

[image: OnePlus One]

Comment: Google sends out the security patches for the next month a few weeks earlier, so manufacturers/carriers can implement them and test them before releasing an OTA in a timely fashion.

Comment: @GiantTree If you are sure, do post an answer. :)

Comment: I think @GiantTree has the point, but nevertheless, there's a small possibility that it's modified in build.prop to display that. Patch note is not released yet so no way to verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GiantTree's](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/156003/android-security-patch-level-from-the-future#comment200064_156003) explanation sounds plausible but there is a bug report raised on first of this month for a patch released last month with similar concern : [Issue 218947:  Security Patch Level shows the future date?](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=218947)

There has been no revert on this from Google, so the cause is uncertain. OP may *star* the bug report to be updated by Google